# CMake can't generate realsense2.lib (visual studio 2017)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cmake, realsense

I must make a project that can detect objects used Intel Realsense D435.

"the Operating System is windows 8.1 x64"

I decided to use Visual Studio 2017, C++, and Opencv for this project. I can work with Opencv in VS2017 but I can't use the Realsense D435 library (librealsense2) with opencv and VS2017, because CMake can't generate this library.
I followed the these Steps "Getting Started", at this [link](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/wrappers/opencv#windows), but when i did step 10, it shows to me these Errors:

*CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2329 (message):
  error: could not find git for clone of libusb
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:3105 (_ep_add_download_command)
  CMakeLists.txt:807 (ExternalProject_Add)*

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS24I.jpg)

How can I fix that?

Could you please tell me what can I do, step by step?

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you got `git` installed in your system? The error message "could not find git for clone of ..." tells exactly about inability to find `git` program.

Comment: I would try [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) for package management.